# pip seems to be broken in virtualenv created with pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, pipenv

When I create a virtual environment with pipenv, start the virtual environment and run pip, the following error appears:

```
me@machine_name:~/prj/PRJ$ pipenv --python 3
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /home/me/prj/PRJ/Pipfile
Using /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python3.9 (3.9.7) to create virtualenv...
⠦ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.9.7.final.0-64 in 363ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/PRJ-KNzNuNcm, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/me/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==21.1.2, setuptools==57.0.0, wheel==0.36.2
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: /home/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/PRJ-KNzNuNcm
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
me@machine_name:~/prj/PRJ$ pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
 . /home/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/PRJ-KNzNuNcm/bin/activate
me@machine_name:~/prj/PRJ$  . /home/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/PRJ-KNzNuNcm/bin/activate
(PRJ) me@machine_name:~/prj/PRJ$ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/PRJ-KNzNuNcm/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR, get_src_prefix
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/locations.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils import appdirs
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/appdirs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import appdirs as _appdirs
ImportError: cannot import name 'appdirs' from 'pip._vendor' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py)
```

How do I modify it to use pip in a virtual environment?

Using

- WSL2 Ubuntu20.04
- pipenv, version 2021.5.29
- python 3.9.7

I'm sorry if there is not enough information. Thank you.

[EDIT]

```
me@machine_name:~/prj/PRJ$ python3 -m pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR, get_src_prefix
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/locations.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils import appdirs
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/appdirs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import appdirs as _appdirs
ImportError: cannot import name 'appdirs' from 'pip._vendor' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py)
```

It looks like linuxbrew's pip is already broken. I asked a question about pipenv, but it may be wrong. But in any case, I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you run `python -m pip --version`?

Comment: Also, you could just skip the `pipenv` and do this: `python -m venv .venv` then `source .venv/bin/activate` and you should have a virtual environment ready to go.

Comment: Thanks. Excecuted python -m pip --version. Please see [EDIT].

Comment: Have you tried just using Python's builtin `venv` module? `python -m venv .venv` then `source .venv/bin/activate`. You can then `pip install` from there.